# Como setar a hora de um "timestamp" para 23:59:59 no postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho em uma célula que contem apenas a data, no caso `2018-07-11`, eu preciso fazer um `select` que vai trazer essa célula assim: `2018-07-11 23:59:59`, é possivel fazer isso?

Comment: No caso vc quer que o select traga a data e a hora, mas na celula só existe a data? seria isso?

Comment: Qual o seu propósito ? Comparar datas ? Já pensou em fazer um CAST para  `DATE` no momento da comparação ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As operações com datas no postgreSQL são faceis de implementar, como vemos na [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

No seu caso basta fazer:

```
SELECT data, data + time '23:59:59'
FROM datas
```

Você pode ver isso funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/666927/3).